# getting JSON data from php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

My PHP web page is returning a JSON string. I wrote following function to get those data and display them on jQuery mobile listview.

```
function LoadJsonDataFunction()
{  
  $.getJSON("my_web_page.php", function(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
      $("ul").append("<li>"+value.fname+"</li>");
    });
  });
}
```

Here is my listview code:

```
<ul data-role=listview> </ul>
```

I have called to the function in the body tag

```
<body onload="LoadJsonDataFunction()">
```

but when I executing the program it displays "undefine" and no data.

then I change $.getJSON() request like this.then its working perfectly.

```
$.getJSON("some_page_returning_same_json_string.json",function(obj) { .....
```

let me know how can i fix this.

PS. Here is my php page output..

```
{
  "employees":[
    {
      "fname": "sdsdsd",
      "lname": "sdsd",
      "phone": "sdsd",
      "gender": "female",
      "dob": "1990-03-11",
      "address": "03",
      "nic": "erer",
      "email": "erererer",
      "empid": "ererere",
      "designation": "sdsds",
      "qualifications": "dsds"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  /*
    Following code will list all the employees
  */

  // array for JSON response
  $response = array();

  // include db connect class
  require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

  // connecting to db
  $db = new DB_CONNECT();

  // get all employees from employees table
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp_master") or die(mysql_error());

  // check for empty result
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // employees node
    $response["employees"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      // temp user array
      $employee = array();
      $employee["fname"] = $row["fname"];
      $employee["lname"] = $row["lname"];
      $employee["phone"] = $row["phone"];
      $employee["gender"] = $row["gender"];
      $employee["dob"] = $row["dob"];
      $employee["address"] = $row["address"];
      $employee["nic"] = $row["nic"];
      $employee["email"] = $row["email"];
      $employee["empid"] = $row["empid"];
      $employee["designation"] = $row["designation"];
      $employee["qualifications"] = $row["qualifications"];

      //push single employee into final response array
      array_push($response["employees"], $employee);
    }
    // success
    // $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response

    echo json_encode($response);
  } else {
    // no employees found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No employees found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
?>
```

Comment: how are you returning json data from PHP end ...?

Comment: Are you returning json string with `json_encode/json_decode` from php?

Comment: Did you tried to add another foreach in your javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
 $.each(obj, function(key, value){
```

with

```
 $.each(obj.employees, function(key, value){
```

The "employees" contains in "obj" and then it contains the array. "obj" does not contain the array you are looking.

Answer (score 3):

Have you write correct header? If not write this as first line in your PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: yes..i have added header after your comment.but still displaying the previous "undefined" item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best [exemple](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/) i used to begin JQM , you can check the link or use the code below

```
$('#ListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    $.getJSON('some_php_or_json_file_link', function(data) {
        $('#listView li').remove();
        $.each(data.items, function(index, item) {
            $('#listView').append('<li><span>' + item.json_label1 + '</span></li>');
        });
        $('#listView').listview('refresh');
    });
});
```